# callback data from servicenot returning back to controller angularjs

Tags: angularjs

find my below code for delete function its deleting in backend and returning success message to service from that not returning to controller ,so was unable to print growl message.

This is my controller side code:

```
$scope.deleteBlogswithid = function(id) {
                                  var loggedInUserId = $rootScope.loggedInUser.id;

                                  if ($rootScope.loggedInUser != null) {


                                    blogService.deleteBlog(id, loggedInUserId,function(data) {
                                        if(data == 'success'){

                                                $location.path("/home");
                                        $growl.box('Blog has been deleted', {  
                                            class : 'danger',
                                            sticky : false,
                                            timeout : 5000
                                        }).open();
                                        }
                                            })
                                } else {
                                    $growl.box('Please login to delete the blog', {  
                                                class : 'danger',
                                                sticky : false,
                                                timeout : 5000
                                            }).open();
                                }

                            }
```

service.js:

```
blogbeatsApp.service('blogService', function(httpService) {
    this.deleteBlog = function(id,loggedInUserId,data, callback) {
        var url = 'blog/delete/' +id + "/" + loggedInUserId;
        httpService.postRequest(url,data, callback);
    };
});
```

httpService.js:this is my httpservice

```
blogbeatsApp.service('httpService', function($http, $location, $rootScope){
    this.postRequest = function(url, data, contentType, callback){
        $http({
            method : 'POST',
            url : url,
            data : data,
            headers : {
                'Content-Type' : contentType
            }
        }).success(function(data) {
            callback(data);
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        });
    };
```

i am not getting success message to controller in function(data).please help

Comment: You does not pass parameter in correct order. `httpService.postRequest(url,data, callback);` your `callback` is 3rd `parameter of postRequest`. Which is bind with `function(url, data, contentType, callback)` - `contentType` since its your 3rd parameter. use this in your httpService `this.postRequest = function(url, data,callback, contentType)` **callback must be 3rd parameter**

Comment: yes..now works.thank u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I say in comments.

You does not pass parameter in correct order.

your `callback` is 3rd parameter of `postRequest`. Which is bind with `function(url, data, contentType, callback)` - `contentType`.

Since, its your **3rd parameter** use this in your `httpService` as  `this.postRequest = function(url, data,callback, contentType)`

> callback must be 3rd parameter

**change httpSerivce** :

```
blogbeatsApp.service('httpService', function($http, $location, $rootScope){
this.postRequest = function(url, data, contentType, callback){
    $http({
        method : 'POST',
        url : url,
        data : data,
        headers : {
            'Content-Type' : contentType
        }
    }).success(function(data) {
        callback(data);
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

    });
};
```

To :

```
blogbeatsApp.service('httpService', function($http, $location, $rootScope){
this.postRequest = function(url, data, callback, contentType){
    // callback should be as 3rd parameter. 
    $http({
        method : 'POST',
        url : url,
        data : data,
        headers : {
            'Content-Type' : contentType
        }
    }).success(function(data) {
        callback(data);
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

    });
};
```